# Is there any way to write html code inside org table that properly be exported as html?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I want to put one line html code inside org table. I wrote following text(see Input below) in org-mode and exported it to html and opened in my browser(see Output below). But the output is not what I expected.

**Input(sample.org):**

```
| No | html code           | desc |
|  1 | #+HTML: <p>hoge</p> | hoge |
```

**Output(sample.html):**

[image]

My expected output is below.

**Expected output(sample.html):**

[image]

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean `<b>hoge</b>`? I don't think that `<p>hoge</p>` makes any sense in a table.

Comment: @NickD: I assume any tag I can use in html, like <p>, <div>, <img>, <table>, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cite from https://orgmode.org/manual/Quoting-HTML-tags.html:

> The HTML export back-end transforms `<` and `>` to `&lt;` and `&gt;`. To include raw HTML code in the Org file so the HTML export back-end can insert that HTML code in the output, use this inline syntax: `@@html:...@@`. For example:
>
> `@@html:<b>@@bold text@@html:</b>@@`

In the following example I use `<i>` instead of `<b>` to separate the formatting from the formatting of the table heading.

```
| my | table                                |
|----+--------------------------------------|
|    | @@html:<i>@@italic text@@html:</i>@@ |
```

Rendered result:

[image: rendered table]

Comment: Thanks. This is what I wanted.:)